# Create registry key in 32-bit hive on x64 PC using Installshield 2012 LE - Avoid redirection

Tags: vsto, installshield-le

I am trying to deploy an Outlook 2010 x64 AddIn in a x64 OS. For this AddIn I have to create the registry keys at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\[add-in ID]`. But Installshield Spring 2012 LE insists in creating the registry keys at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\[add-in ID]`.

I know there's a redirection of the registry creation taking place, but how do I avoid this redirection? The AddIn registry keys need to be created in the 32-bits hive in order for it to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm having the same issue! How did you resolve it? Also on a separate question, how did you create a self signed certificate and add it to the adding? Thanks.

Comment: @HM1, Open your setup in VS, go to the "Organize Your Setup" section at "General Information". There change the property "ALLUSERS" to "ALLUSERS=""(Per-user installation)". This will make the Installshield create the registry keys in the 32-bit hive of the registry.

Answer (score 0):

Open your setup in VS, go to the "Organize Your Setup" section at "General Information". There change the property "ALLUSERS" to "ALLUSERS=""(Per-user installation)". This will make the Installshield create the registry keys in the 32-bit hive of the registry. –  Joe Almore Oct 10 '13 at 3:03