# Autostart application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, installshield

How do i configure the free version of installshield that comes with visual studio 2012 to automatically start my application each time the pc is booted for ALL users? I assume this is in the application Registry section. My users will have both 32 and 64 bit versions of operating systems.

Comment: Are you wanting a copy that is started when a user logs in (so multiple copies could be running if there are multiple users logged in) and interacts with their session or are you looking for something that starts when the computer starts even if no one is logged in and only has one copy running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

windows 7 redirection is the cause of my issue - you need to follow the process here if you want to see the value in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run

[Create registry key in 32-bit hive on x64 PC using Installshield 2012 LE - Avoid redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18860957/create-registry-key-in-32-bit-hive-on-x64-pc-using-installshield-2012-le-avoid)

Answer (score 3):

I believe the registry key that you might be looking for is: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run

http://www.cwu.edu/~ddavis/Help%20Files/Windows/Windows_how_to_manage_startup.htm

Comment: understood but i am looking for specific Installshield instructions

Comment: Sorry, missed that bit. I've used the following link before and it has helped me. I've just had another look and it contains some information about the registry:

http://codesmartnothard.com/InstallShieldLimitedEditionForVisualStudio2010Walkthrough.aspx accompanied with http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield16helplib/IHelpRegistryKeys.htm

Comment: yes but nothing with specific reference to the question.